# One to one correspondence between the set of even natural numbers ($2\mathbb{N}$) and the set of integers excluding 0 ($\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is there a way to make a one to one correspondence between the set of even natural numbers and the set of integers not including 0? What would that function be?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You should also tell what are your ideas in solving this question. This would not attract downvotes and will prevent the question from being closed due to low quality. For more details on how to write a good question, you may refer here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: They are both countable infinite sets, so of course there is a one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: What would it look like? As a function

Comment: I can't figure out the piecewise function?

Comment: Find a correspondence between the first set and the naturals, and a correspondence between the second set and the naturals, and then do a composition.

Comment: You've had a couple of answers, Sanchit. If you're happy with one of them, you can "accept" it by clicking in the check mark next to it. If you're not happy, you could leave comments to show what you still need.

Comment: You could do that today, Sanchit.

Answer (score 1):

Take the multiples of $4$ to the positive integers and the numbers equivalent to $2 \bmod 4$ to the negative integers.

Comment: So any number that is not a multiple of 4 and is an even natural number will have a modulus = 2 when I take x mod 4. So could you express this as a piecewise function so I can see it clearly

Comment: Wold it just be: F(x) = {x, if x=4n
                                   {-x, if n%4=2

Comment: No, try a few small values and you will find you miss a bunch of integers.  $f(2)=-2, f(4)=4,f(6)=-6,f(8)=8, \ldots $  You need a divide by $4$ because the steps in the domain are $4$ and the step you want in the range are $1$.  You are getting there.

Comment: Oh okay. I see. But how do I fix the negative integers? If I divide by 4 for the x modulus 4 statement, I will get rational numbers.

Comment: You add $2$ before dividing by $4$

Answer (score 0):

$$\matrix{x&2&4&6&8&10&\cdots\cr n&1&2&3&4&5&\cdots\cr y&1&-1&2&-2&3&\cdots\cr}$$ If $n$ is odd, then $y=(x+2)/4$; if $n$ is even, then $y=-x/4$.